# Is it possible to toggle transparency mode with code?

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, airpods

I want to build an app that automates the transparency and noise cancelation features of the AirPods Pro. The idea is to open the app, put the AirPod Pros in ears (transparency mode by default), start a countdown timer which turns on noise cancelation, then switch to transparency mode when the timer runs out. I don't need to play any audio.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Hello! I know that this is not accepted. But for a long time I cannot resolve the issue. Could you help me? I would be very grateful. I can't find AirPods Pro in my area. Could you just open up my small xcode project and test it please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69851479/audio-files-wont-play-with-airpods-pro-on-ios-15

Answer (score 0):

There is currently (as of this writing) no public API for control of AirPods.

There have been [a](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/97554) [few](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/74764) threads asking similar questions on Apple's official Developer forums, to the same end answer.

In this case, it might be easier to think about it from Apple's perspective: if Apple did allow control of AirPods in this manner, it could open up huge possibilities for major end user confusion ("Why was noise cancelling disabled without my explicit say-so?", or users who wouldn't *realize* noise cancelling was disabled and instead believe their product is faulty). For Apple, a decision between utility and user experience generally tips toward the latter.

In this same line of thinking, I'm hard-pressed to come up with a situation where Apple would elect to publicly release an API enabling developers to control the functionality you describe in your question.